# PolyBase to CSV File

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, csv, polybase

I'm trying to see if it's possible to create a PolyBase connection to a .CSV file.  I'm using the Microsoft Access Text Driver and have set up a system DSN to the folder where the csv file is located.  I'm able to query the file using OPENROWSET and the DSN, but when I try creating the external table, I'm getting the following generic error.

```
Msg 105082, Level 16, State 1, Line 108
105082;Generic ODBC error: [Microsoft][ODBC Text Driver]Optional feature not implemented
```

The file is just a simple one I created with three columns and two rows.  Would it be possible to create a PolyBase connection to a .csv file?

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL CSVFile
WITH IDENTITY ='ident',SECRET='pass'

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE CSV
WITH ( LOCATION = 'odbc://localhost'
       ,CONNECTION_OPTIONS = 'Driver={Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};DSN=CSVs'
        ,CREDENTIAL = CSVFile
        );

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE TestCSV
(
    Col1 VARCHAR(255) NULL
    ,Col2 VARCHAR(255) NULL
    ,Col3 VARCHAR(255) NULL
)
WITH
(
    LOCATION = N'Test.csv',
    DATA_SOURCE = CSV
)
GO
```

Comment: I'm not super experienced with the Polybase stuff, but I'd start by trying the latest ODBC driver release. I'm *guessing* the Access one you're using is a bit old in the teeth.

Comment: From what I've seen that driver is the latest and greatest 64 bit text file driver from Microsoft, unless I purchase one from a third party.

Comment: What version is it?

Comment: Microsoft Access Text Driver 14.00.7010.1000

Comment: The latest [ODBC version is 17](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) I'd suggest trying that one.

Comment: @MrTCS did you find a fix? I have a similar issue.

Comment: @RaviLobo I did not but I found some 3rd party connectors from CDATA we are going to try. This wasn’t urgent so we have not tried them yet though.

Comment: @MrTCS Thank you. I too found the CDATA driver [link](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/csv-odbc-polybase.rst). However, it is not free.

Comment: @MrTCS check this link [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61100707/polybase-to-connect-local-csv-file). This might help.